# Show that halfspaces,hyperplanes and lines does not have any extreme points.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Show that halfspaces,hyperplanes and lines does not have any extreme points.

---

Let $\text{L}(\bar x,\text{d}):=\{\bar x+t\text{d}:t \in \mathbb R\}$

For any $ z \in \text{L}(\bar x,\text{d})$, let $\lambda=1/2$ and $A=\bar x+t'/2\text{d},B=\bar x+3t'/2\text{d}$, where $z=\bar x+t'\text{d}$, so $$z=\frac{A+B}{2}$$ and $A\ne B$,
this shows that every point in $\text{L}(\bar x,\text{d})$  is not an extreme point of $\text{L}(\bar x,\text{d})$, so lines does not have any extreme points.

---

Every hyperplane can be written as $H:=\{x:\text{p}^t (x-x_0)=0\}$ for some $x_0 \in H$.

For any $ z \in H$,and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ if for some $A,B \in H$: $$z=\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B$$

Then since $A,B \in H$ we conclude that $\text{p}^t (A-x_0)=0$  and $\text{p}^t (B-x_0)=0$,so:
$$\text{p}^t (A-x_0)=\text{p}^t (B-x_0)$$
$$(\text{p}^t)^{-1}\text{p}^t (A-x_0)=(\text{p}^t)^{-1}\text{p}^t (B-x_0)$$
$$A= B$$

So hyperplanes does not have any extreme points.
However here I assumed that the inverse of $\text{p}^t$ does exist, and I'm not sure if that really exist.

---

Every half-space can be written as $H^+:=\{x:\text{p}^t (x-x_0)\ge 0\}$ or $H^-:=\{x:\text{p}^t (x-x_0)\le 0\}$ for some $x_0 \in H$.

For any $ z \in H$,and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ if for some $A,B \in H^+$: $$z=\lambda A+(1-\lambda)B$$
Then this is equivalent to
$$\text{p}^t (z-x_0)=\lambda \text{p}^t (A-x_0)+(1-\lambda)\text{p}^t (B-x_0)$$

The LHS of the equality is non-negative, if it's equal to $0$, then since $\lambda \text{p}^t (A-x_0)$ and $\lambda \text{p}^t (B-x_0)$ are also non-negative, then we conclude that both are zero, but the range of $\lambda$ implies that $$\text{p}^t (A-x_0)=0=\text{p}^t (B-x_0)$$

Which then shows that $A=B$, But what if The LHS of the equality is positive?

Comment: You don't need to go to this length. For a start, extreme points must be on the boundary, and the boundary of a half-plane is a hyperplane. More generally non-degenerate affine subspaces do not have extreme points. These contain all lines containing any two points in them. So just take the line containing a given point and another. Take a point on this line on the other side, and then the original point is a convex combination.

Answer (score 1):

Halfspace: Clearly we cant have an interior point $v$ be extreme since we can take points $v+\varepsilon w$ and $v-\varepsilon w$ contained in the set for small enough $\varepsilon$. So extreme points are on the boundary. The boundary of the half-space $\{v\ |\ \langle w,v\rangle\geq k\}$ is the hyperplane $\{v\ |\ \langle w,v\rangle=k\}$, by the continuity of the inner product on $V\times V$, for vector space $V$. Clearly if a point is extreme in $S$ with $T\subseteq S$, it is extreme in $T$. So this boils down to the result for affine subspaces.

Non-degenerate affine subspaces: Affine subspaces $P$ contain all lines between points $v,w\in P$. This one way to define them, but if it's not the one you want to use it's trivial anyway. Now, let $v\in P$. We intend to show that $v$ is not extreme. So take $w\neq v$ with $w\in P$. Then $w+k(v-w)\in P$ for all $k\in\mathbb{R}$ by definition. So take $x:=w+2(v-w)=2v-w$. Then $v=\frac{w}{2}+\frac{x}{2}$, a convex combination.

Comment: Your half-space is given by $\{v\ |\ \langle w,v\rangle\geq k\}$, while I've been told that every half-space can be written as $H^+:=\{x:\text{p}^t (x-x_0)\ge 0\}$ or $H^-:=\{x:\text{p}^t (x-x_0)\le 0\}$ for some $x_0 \in H$, I don't understand the notations, can you explain your answer with my notations?

Comment: $\langle w,v\rangle$ is just $w^tv$ for fixed $w$. That these formulations are equivalent is easy. So you need that $w^tv$ is continuous on $V\times V$.